# Use custom component in overlay attribute in AntD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to add a custom right-click menu component to a menu item. I can do it via a const but when I do it with a component, styles seems to work wrong. Any idea?

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/m5n31opx2j

My custom menu:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Dropdown from "antd/lib/dropdown";
import Menu from "antd/lib/menu";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

export default class MyMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item
          onClick={e => {
            alert("clicked");
          }}
        >
          click
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item>Like it</Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item>Bookmark</Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}
```

My main component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Dropdown from "antd/lib/dropdown";
import Menu from "antd/lib/menu";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import MyMenu from "./MyMenu";

const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item
      onClick={e => {
        alert("clicked");
      }}
    >
      click
    </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Like it</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Bookmark</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu mode="horizontal">
          <Menu.Item
            key="1"
            onClick={() => {
              alert("parent clicked");
            }}
          >
            <Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={[`contextMenu`]}>
              <span style={{ userSelect: "none" }}> from const </span>
            </Dropdown>
          </Menu.Item>

          <Menu.Item
            key="2"
            onClick={() => {
              alert("parent clicked");
            }}
          >
            <Dropdown overlay={<MyMenu />} trigger={[`contextMenu`]}>
              <span style={{ userSelect: "none" }}> from component </span>
            </Dropdown>
          </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const APP_NODE = document.getElementById(`container`);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, APP_NODE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in component you are wrapping `Menu` with react class. And you loose inheritance of antd `Dropdown` component.

So you need to pass `Menu` directly to `overlay` property of `Dropdown` component as you did it with constant `menu`:

That is just how component works.

To stay with custom component approach, you need to include `Dropdown` in `MyMenu` component so that `Menu` is passed directly to `overlay` prop:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Dropdown from "antd/lib/dropdown";
import Menu from "antd/lib/menu";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const menu = (
  <Menu>
    <Menu.Item
      onClick={e => {
        alert("clicked");
      }}
    >
      click
  </Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Like it</Menu.Item>
    <Menu.Item>Bookmark</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
);

export default class MyMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={[`contextMenu`]}>
        <span style={{ userSelect: "none" }}> from const </span>
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Here you can see directly in the source code how that is done:
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/557683c7644d2aef1e2df0490815b294b063d457/components/dropdown/dropdown.tsx#L74

Comment: What do you mean by directly? `overlay=<MyMenu />` and `overlay=MyMenu` both not working.

Comment: I mean the way you did it with first example that works with constant. So directly as dom elements. You can make a separated component for this, but include `Dropdown` component there, not to put that component inside `Dropdown`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.